# How to find the right version of my docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do I find the right compose file [version](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/) for my `docker-compose.yml` file?

I have this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  ghost:
    container_name: ghost
    image: ghost:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:2368:2368
    volumes:
      -v /var/www/myBlog/:/var/lib/ghost
```

and I have installed Docker Engine - Community version: `19.03.8`

How can I know it?

Thanks

Comment: See "Compatibility matrix" behind your link: 3.7 is current and that version of Docker should work with it.

Comment: It should work, but is not working @DavidMaze

Comment: @DavidMaze if I remove the volume it works, so the question is, how can I bind the folder at the docker later to my host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about the `-v` under your volumes?

Please check the [#volume-configuration-reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) for docker-compose files.

You need to mention it like below.

```
volumes:
  - /var/www/myBlog/:/var/lib/ghost
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the volume to below

```
 volumes:
  - /var/www/myBlog/:/var/lib/ghost
```

There is a compatibility matrix between Docker Engine and `docker-compose`

> https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

Below is the changelog of `docker-compose` and `docker` which can help you understand various features available in which version.

> Docker-compose:- https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
>
> Docker-ce:- https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases